# Android Studio Closed automatically in ubuntu

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Please see the log file below... same problem from last 3 months, that is from android studio 1.2 to new version.

I have tried may ways no use!!!

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007f588d12597e, pid=11303, tid=140017682175744
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_60-b27) (build 1.8.0_60-b27)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.60-b23 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# V  [libjvm.so+0x47497e]  PhaseConservativeCoalesce::update_ifg(unsigned int, unsigned int, IndexSet*, IndexSet*)+0x40e
#
# Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
#

---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x00007f58880f9800):  JavaThread "C2 CompilerThread0" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=11315, stack(0x00007f5868255000,0x00007f5868356000)]

siginfo: si_signo: 11 (SIGSEGV), si_code: 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), si_addr: 0x0000000000000008

Registers:
RAX=0x0000000000000002, RBX=0x00007f5849318010, RCX=0x0000000000000000, RDX=0x00000000000009d5
RSP=0x00007f5868351290, RBP=0x00007f58683513d0, RSI=0x0000000000000002, RDI=0x0000000000000009
R8 =0x000000000000000a, R9 =0x0000000024012209, R10=0x0000000000000000, R11=0x0000000049249248
R12=0x00000000000009d5, R13=0x00007f5868351590, R14=0x00007f58683512e0, R15=0x00000000ffffffbf
RIP=0x00007f588d12597e, EFLAGS=0x0000000000010287, CSGSFS=0x0000000000000033, ERR=0x0000000000000004
  TRAPNO=0x000000000000000e
```

Comment: Probably should file that as an Android Studio bug.  http://tools.android.com/filing-bugs

Comment: I filed lot many times no use :(